# react webpack build error: Range out of order in character class - component package breaks build due to styles

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

I can't load imported css / scss styles from 3rd party packages or cdn links. The styles load fine locally, but when I run a build `webpack -p --mode production` the entire app breaks and I get an indistinguishable error. It's trying to load a private component project that was built with create-react-app.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[A-Za-zÂªÂµÂºÃ€-Ã–Ã˜-Ã¶Ã¸-ËË†-Ë‘Ë -Ë¤Ë¬Ë®Í°-Í´Í¶Í·Íº-Í½Î†Îˆ-ÎŠÎŒÎŽ-Î¡Î£-ÏµÏ·-ÒÒŠ-Ô§Ô±-Õ–Õ™Õ¡-Ö‡×-×ª×°-×²Ø -ÙŠÙ®Ù¯Ù±-Û“Û•Û¥Û¦Û®Û¯Ûº-Û¼Û¿ÜÜ’-Ü¯Ý-Þ¥Þ±ßŠ-ßªß´ßµßºà €-à •à šà ¤à ¨à¡€-à¡˜à¢ à¢¢-à¢¬à¤„-à¤¹à¤½à¥à¥˜-à¥¡à¥±-à¥·à¥¹-à¥¿à¦…-à¦Œà¦à¦à¦“-à¦¨à¦ª-à¦°à¦²à¦¶-à¦¹à¦½à§Žà§œà§à§Ÿ-à§¡à§°à§±à¨…-à¨Šà¨à¨à¨“-à¨¨à¨ª-à¨°à¨²à¨³à¨µà¨¶à¨¸à¨¹à©™-à©œà©žà©²-à©´àª…-àªàª-àª‘àª“-àª¨àªª-àª°àª²àª³àªµ-àª¹àª½à«à« à«¡à¬…-à¬Œà¬à¬à¬“-à¬¨à¬ª-à¬°à¬²à¬³à¬µ-à¬¹à¬½à­œà­à­Ÿ-à­¡à­±à®ƒà®…-à®Šà®Ž-à®à®’-à®•à®™à®šà®œà®žà®Ÿà®£à®¤à®¨-à®ªà®®-à®¹à¯à°…-à°Œà°Ž-à°à°’-à°¨à°ª-à°³à°µ-à°¹à°½à±˜à±™à± à±¡à²…-à²Œà²Ž-à²à²’-à²¨à²ª-à²³à²µ-à²¹à²½à³žà³ à³¡à³±à³²à´…-à´Œà´Ž-à´à´’-à´ºà´½àµŽàµ àµ¡àµº-àµ¿à¶…-à¶–à¶š-à¶±à¶³-à¶»à¶½à·€-à·†à¸-à¸°à¸²à¸³à¹€-à¹†àºàº‚àº„àº‡àºˆàºŠàºàº”-àº—àº™-àºŸàº¡-àº£àº¥àº§àºªàº«àº­-àº°àº²àº³àº½à»€-à»„à»†à»œ-à»Ÿà¼€à½€-à½‡à½‰-à½¬à¾ˆ-à¾Œá€€-á€ªá€¿á-á•áš-áá¡á¥á¦á®-á°áµ-á‚á‚Žá‚ -áƒ…áƒ‡áƒáƒ-áƒºáƒ¼-á‰ˆá‰Š-á‰á‰-á‰–á‰˜á‰š-á‰á‰ -áŠˆáŠŠ-áŠáŠ-áŠ°áŠ²-áŠµáŠ¸-áŠ¾á‹€á‹‚-á‹…á‹ˆ-á‹–á‹˜-áŒáŒ’-áŒ•áŒ˜-ášáŽ€-áŽáŽ -á´á-á™¬á™¯-á™¿áš-áššáš -á›ªáœ€-áœŒáœŽ-áœ‘áœ -áœ±á€-á‘á -á¬á®-á°áž€-áž³áŸ—áŸœá  -á¡·á¢€-á¢¨á¢ªá¢°-á£µá¤€-á¤œá¥-á¥­á¥°-á¥´á¦€-á¦«á§-á§‡á¨€-á¨–á¨ -á©”áª§á¬…-á¬³á­…-á­‹á®ƒ-á® á®®á®¯á®º-á¯¥á°€-á°£á±-á±á±š-á±½á³©-á³¬á³®-á³±á³µá³¶á´€-á¶¿á¸€-á¼•á¼˜-á¼á¼ -á½…á½ˆ-á½á½-á½—á½™á½›á½á½Ÿ-á½½á¾€-á¾´á¾¶-á¾¼á¾¾á¿‚-á¿„á¿†-á¿Œá¿-á¿“á¿–-á¿›á¿ -á¿¬á¿²-á¿´á¿¶-á¿¼â±â¿â‚-â‚œâ„‚â„‡â„Š-â„“â„•â„™-â„â„¤â„¦â„¨â„ª-â„­â„¯-â„¹â„¼-â„¿â……-â…‰â…Žâ†ƒâ†„â°€-â°®â°°-â±žâ± -â³¤â³«-â³®â³²â³³â´€-â´¥â´§â´­â´°-âµ§âµ¯â¶€-â¶–â¶ -â¶¦â¶¨-â¶®â¶°-â¶¶â¶¸-â¶¾â·€-â·†â·ˆ-â·Žâ·-â·–â·˜-â·žâ¸¯ã€…ã€†ã€±-ã€µã€»ã€¼ã-ã‚–ã‚-ã‚Ÿã‚¡-ãƒºãƒ¼-ãƒ¿ã„…-ã„­ã„±-ã†Žã† -ã†ºã‡°-ã‡¿ã€-ä¶µä¸€-é¿Œê€€-ê’Œê“-ê“½ê”€-ê˜Œê˜-ê˜Ÿê˜ªê˜«ê™€-ê™®ê™¿-êš—êš -ê›¥êœ—-êœŸêœ¢-êžˆêž‹-êžŽêž-êž“êž -êžªêŸ¸-ê ê ƒ-ê …ê ‡-ê Šê Œ-ê ¢ê¡€-ê¡³ê¢‚-ê¢³ê£²-ê£·ê£»ê¤Š-ê¤¥ê¤°-ê¥†ê¥ -ê¥¼ê¦„-ê¦²ê§ê¨€-ê¨¨ê©€-ê©‚ê©„-ê©‹ê© -ê©¶ê©ºêª€-êª¯êª±êªµêª¶êª¹-êª½ê«€ê«‚ê«›-ê«ê« -ê«ªê«²-ê«´ê¬-ê¬†ê¬‰-ê¬Žê¬‘-ê¬–ê¬ -ê¬¦ê¬¨-ê¬®ê¯€-ê¯¢ê°€-íž£íž°-íŸ†íŸ‹-íŸ»ï¤€-ï©­ï©°-ï«™ï¬€-ï¬†ï¬“-ï¬—ï¬ï¬Ÿ-ï¬¨ï¬ª-ï¬¶ï¬¸-ï¬¼ï¬¾ï­€ï­ï­ƒï­„ï­†-ï®±ï¯“-ï´½ïµ-ï¶ï¶’-ï·‡ï·°-ï·»ï¹°-ï¹´ï¹¶-ï»¼ï¼¡-ï¼ºï½-ï½šï½¦-ï¾¾ï¿‚-ï¿‡ï¿Š-ï¿ï¿’-ï¿—ï¿š-ï¿œ]/: Range out of order in character class
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (parsePhoneNumber.js:23)
    at r (bootstrap:63)
    at Object.<anonymous> (Leniency.js:246)
    at r (bootstrap:63)
    at Object.<anonymous> (findNumbers.js:5)
    at r (bootstrap:63)
    at Module.<anonymous> (index.js:1)
    at r (bootstrap:63)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.scss:3)
```

Here is my webpack config:

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const AssetsPlugin = require("assets-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist/",
        filename: "index.js",
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /(\.png|\.svg|\.jpg)$/,
                loader: "url-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'style-loader' },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                            // sourceMap: true,
                            // importLoaders: 1
                        }
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'style-loader' },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                            sourceMap: true,
                            importLoaders: 1
                        }
                    },
                    { loader: 'sass-loader' }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { context: "src", from: "**/*" }
        ], {
                ignore: ["*.js", "*.scss", "*.css"]
            }),
        new AssetsPlugin({
            filename: "assets.json",
            useCompilerPath: true,
            keepInMemory: true,
            metadata: {
                buildDate: Date.now(),
                buildVersion: require("./package.json").version,
                exclude: [
                    "flags/"
                ]
            }
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            toolboxTheme: 'theme.scss'
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: Have you ever been able to solve this?